# PyMongo not working in Django Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, macos, pymongo

I am trying to integrate MongoDB in my Django Project. For this I have installed Mongo and PyMongo in my Mac system and everything looks fine. I tried executing some PyMongo code in python shell and it worked fine.

But when I try to `from pymongo import Connection` in my DJango project it gives import error. I am not sure where I went wrong.

Can someone suggest a way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Issue fixed. Just uninstall and reinstal PyMongo.

```
 sudo pip uninstall pymongo
 sudo pip install pymongo -U
```